# Texture memory on iPad/iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

Does anybody know how much texture memory will be available for OpenGL on the new iPhone 4? How much is on the iPad?

Thanks!

Comment: See here http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ipad-3-benchmark-review,3156-6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerVR SGX-based iDevices (Phone, Pad, Touch, and I suspect the upcoming TV refresh) use a unified memory system - there's no separate 24MB "video memory" limitation as there is in the MBX-based ones. You'll be limited only by the total available free memory.